# My Android Application Crashes when I shared it to other devices

Tags: android

My Application crashes after sending its apk to other devices, it installed yet when I tried to open it ,even at just the beginning it crashes. Someone help me please

SampleAcct01

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Are the mobiles same versions? or  Is the Application  using any your mobile folders which are not in other mobiles?suppose if you give a path for any resources if it is not in another device it crashes.run in crashed mobile and check logcat.That is the way to see what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

application crashes.means you have to check error  at log cat 
so for crash application, a lots of resons may be 
1. if min sdk version not matched with other device
2. which higest sdk version you have used in your application
3.cooding mistakes ..likes..example .getting directly integer value in string
a lots of reasons are there.
so use  the log cat in every methods & after getting veriables

so you can confirm why you getting problem

so first you have to check..min sdk  version..and maximum sdk version
then check cooding